# Is daily drawing fair?

Tags: dragon-city

There's a daily drawing in Dragon City, where you choose one of the cards and get a reward. Between drawing the cards are shown to you, and there are various rewards including crystals. But as for now, I've got only the lowest value rewards.

Is that drawing really honest? By honest I understand, the cards are really mixed and you have the same probability to get each of rewards. I can't exclude I've had misluck, but maybe it's not a real drawing, and it doesn't matter what card you click, an algorithm decides what you get.

Answering that questions would require, of course, a large series of tries and summing up the information from the other players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing for a longer time, and analyzing it logically, I'm sure the drawing is cheated.

First, I almost always get 'next drawing chance' or the lowest gold/food prize. I've only once or twice gained middle gold/food.

Second, there are 9 cards. The extra drawing costs 3 gems, and the biggest prize is 50 gems. It's easy to calculate, that investing 27 gems would give you 50. It's certainly something no game provider would ever allow.

So no matter what card you click, the system will only then make drawing, and surely the probability of winning higher prizes is very low, and what's worse, only game operator knows exactly how low.

Use the free drawing as soon as available, but don't invest gems. The system is so designed for you to loose money there.